# a:active is not working

Tags: html, css

I am quite confused here,

the `a:active` is not working , but the `:hover` is working fine,
I have tried a lot of things but this ones is got me stuck, and is really confusing.
I have just added links in the table, I have added the cells to the class, `.menu1`. now when I visit the active page, the active link is not highlited.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<table style="margin-bottom:15px" >
 <tr>
    <td><a href="ts_cms.php"><img src="../images/admin/prop_btn.png"></a></td>
    <td><a href="#"><img src="../images/admin/pack_btn.png"></a></td>
    <td> <a href="#"><img src="../images/admin/blog_btn.png"></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="ts_cms.php">Add property</a></td>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">Add package</a></td>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">Add Blog</a></td>
 </tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">Remove property</a></td>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">Remove package</a></td>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">Remove Blog</a></td>
 </tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">Update property</a></td>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">Update package</a></td>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">Update Blog</a></td>
 </tr>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">List all properties</a></td>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">List all packages</a></td>
    <td class= "menu1"><a href="#">List all Blogs</a></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

CSS:

```
.menu1 {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:auto;
  margin-left:10px;
  background-position:center;
  background-image:url(../images/admin/menu_1.png);
  vertical-align:central;
  text-align:center;
  color:#FFF;
}
    ,
.menu1:hover {
    color:#0CF;
    background-image:url(../images/admin/menu_1_hover.png);
}

.menu1 a {
    color:#FFF;
}  

.menu1 a:hover {
    color:#0CF;
} 

.menu1 a:active {
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Just a pointer, there shouldn't be a comma between `.menu1` and `.menu1 a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:active` doesn't mean "has an `href` attribute that resolves to the URL of the current page".
It means "While being activated" (e.g. clicked on). You can use it for things like making something that looks like a button look like it is being depressed when it is clicked on.

CSS doesn't have a selector for "has an `href` attribute that resolves to the URL of the current page". You'll need to modify the DOM instead. Typically you would do this by generating your navigation menu server side and either adding an extra class or removing the `<a>` element (and maybe using a `<span>` instead) for the current page.

Answer (score 0):

As @quentin mentions, you cannot use CSS to determine whether a `href` refers to an actual url or not, but you can use the attribute selector in CSS to check for specific values for the `href`:

```
.menu1 a[href="#"]{
  color: #000;
}
```

You can check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for more information about attribute selectors.

Answer (score -1):

`a:active` is when u `click and hold the link`. Not for the active selection. I would recommend to use Js for the active Menu object :)

Note // your closed two `</tr>`Tags - but you only needed to close one. Edited that for you.